# Having onchange event fire when input value set from data

Tags: ractivejs

I've been looking at many two-way data binding libraries and so far haven't found one that will fire  onchange events when the input's value is set from a change on the model.  Is there any way to do that with ractive.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but is a little bit hacky. Browsers only fire the `change` event as a result of user interaction (rather than `input.value = 'someNewValue'`), so you have to watch the model and fire the event yourself:

```js
var ractive = new Ractive({
    el: 'main',
    template: '#template',
    data: { name: 'world' },
    twoway: false
});

ractive.observe( 'name', function () {
    // name has changed, need to simulate an event
    var event = new Event( 'change' );
    ractive.find( 'input' ).dispatchEvent( event );
});

ractive.find( 'input' ).addEventListener( 'change', function ( event ) {
    console.log( 'event was fired', event );
});

// check the console!
ractive.set( 'name', 'everybody' );
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>

<main></main>

<script id='template' type='text/ractive'>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
    <input value='{{name}}'/>
</script>
```

Note that twoway binding has been disabled, otherwise you'd get extra events firing all over the place when the user *did* interact with the input - so you would need to listen for `input`/`change` events and handle those interactions yourself.

Comment: At least it's doable, albeit at the expense of two-way binding. It would be nice if it was just an option so that ractive knew to fire the change event when setting the value.  I shall read the docs again about synthetic events and maybe I can have an event other than change run the same function as the change event, then I can keep two-way binding.  I'm new to SO so I can't upvote your answer, but it's given me a good place to start!

Answer (score 0):

The answer (for my purposes) is actually quite simple.  First a little background - which I probably should have outlined in the original question.  Let's say you're viewing/editing a customer profile.  Meanwhile someone else is doing the same.  They update a phone# and resave the profile.  Without anything special being done you aren't going to see that new phone# unless you reload the profile.  My goal is to make our data/forms 'reactive'.  One of the difficulties was updating a form.  In itself that's easy enough but how to handle any onchange events on inputs.  Let's say a country is changed so a new list of regions needs to appear.  Me changing the country would fire off the country's onchange event and a new list would appear.  If a reactive change occurred and updated the country the onchange wouldn't fire.  That's a problem.  To make a long story short, the answer is to not have any onchange events on inputs but have a Ractive.on('change') event and then parse the key path for anything of interest.  That will catch changes from the human and changes from the 'beyond', either with set or merge.

```js
var cust = {
    firstname: 'Fred',
    lastname: 'Flintstone'
}

ractive = new Ractive({
    el: '#spot',
    template: '#tmpl1',
    data: {customer: cust},
    lazy: true
})

ractive.on('change', function(kp) {
    console.log(kp)
})

setTimeout(function() {
    ractive.set('customer.firstname', 'Wilma')
}, 2000)

setTimeout(function() {
    ractive.merge('customer', {firstname: 'Barney', lastname: 'Rubble'})
}, 4000)
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id='spot'></div>
    <script id='tmpl1' type='text/tmpl'>
        <input value={{customer.firstname}}>
        <input value={{customer.lastname}}>
    </script>
</body>
```